# Maven can't discover workspace projects, junit, other libraries

Tags: maven, windows-xp, m2e

so I have started using maven (with eclipse, and a local implementation of Sonatype) not that long ago, after getting through the initial pain I though everything was working.... apparently not !

I have my main project POM and all my child POM (I am using a 'flat' hierarchy, so all the sub projects are in the same folder as the parent POM). This seems to be working OK.

The sub project where all started and 'released' and tested before I started using Maven. I went to maven to solve my 'dependencies' problems... or rather make them more complicated in this instance.

Most of the 'Maven' stuff seems to work fine, but I can't resolve the dependencies of my 'sub projects' that have been released into my local ms/repository

Each day I start up eclipse and have the same problems, I have 'unable to resolve imports' on all my personal libraries, and all those that I use for them (such as Log4j, DDlUtils etc).

I thought the whole point of maven was that I would be able to put in an import declaration for a library, add the 'groupID' and other stuff to the child POM (or parent POM). And then have all the jars downloaded automagically when I run 
    mvn install
against the parent.

However each day I find I have to re-insert the build path to the libraries (internal and external) via the eclipse workspace and point them to the location of the libraries that I have downloaded as maven can't seem to find them anywhere.

Specifically with running Junit test, I can run them from the workspace (using run as junit) and they all pass fine. But if I try to run them with 
    mvn test
I get an message saying
    java.lang;NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert
(and this is the same from within eclipse running the mvn test or from CLI) 
with an error message in the output of
    failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven.surfire-plugin:2.10:test
the POM and jar are in my M2_REPO, and I can find it when I search in sonatype, why can't maven find something that is part of its own system, exists in its repo.

but this obviously works just fine when I run via eclipse and point it to an independently downloaded junit library.

I don't know what extra info you may require, and I'm obviously missing something in either the m2e plugin, my maven install or in sonatype.

please help I'm begining to loose my hair!
and may soon be forced to return to an ant/ivy solution (but don't want to have to learn 'yet another tool' (in this case ivy).

Thanks in advance

David.

ps. i'm on a windows XP platform

edit...
can I get maven to build and release the jar and pom even though it thinks it is failing the tests (which is itn't as I'm doing them manually, and they pass just fine).

If I look in the 'effective POM' tab of my parent POM, the plugin stated above is not in there. I guess this means it is a maven config setting, but where do I add it, and why isn't it automatic when I run my first set of maven tests?

edit 2....

I just found this on the apache plugin comments page (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/plugin-info.html), so I ran the code on the CLI,    mvn surefire:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=test   lots of stuff was downloaded, and now the tests run, but they fail within maven ? (remember they pass when run from eclipse using 'run as junit test)... so this is nearly a solution...

Comment: mvn surefire:help -Ddetail=true -Dgoal=test

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need make eclipse aware that the projects in question are Maven projects. You may have POMs set up for your projects, but for the m2e plugin to work you need to have either created the project as a Maven project ('New' -> 'Project...' -> 'Maven' -> 'Maven Project...'), or converted it into a Maven project by right clicking it then selecting 'Configure' -> 'Convert to Maven Project'. You will know that a project has been recognised as a Maven project because there will be a little blue 'M' in the top left of its icon, as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Some Maven eclipse projects]

The main thing to note in the above picture is the 'Maven Dependencies' library. This is set up automatically by the m2e plugin. Whenever you add a dependency to a POM then the project's build path will be configured automatically, although sometimes you may need to force it to do so by right clicking the project and selecting 'Maven' -> 'Update Maven Configuration'. The important thing is that if everything is working then you should never have to update the build path yourself. Moveover, if you do update it yourself then any changes you make will likely get overwritten the next time you run the 'Update Maven Configuration' command.

Also worth noting from the picture is that the two dependencies 'mavenProjectTest' and 'primes' have folder icons next to them. This means that they have been picked up as workspace projects. For this to work the project must have 'workspace resolution' enabled, and the projects to be picked up need to be configured as m2e Maven projects as well.

You mention downloading external libraries. You shouldn't need to download any libraries yourself - by adding the right dependency declaration for an external library then Maven will download it from your configured remote repository (the first time anyway - afterwards it will then be able to get it from your local repository). By default, this is the [Maven Central repository](http://search.maven.org/). To add an external library to your project just follow that link, enter the library in the search box, click on the version link for the version you require, then you will be taken to a page where there will be the dependency XML declaration that you can just copy and paste into your POM.

One more thing that may help is that you should make sure that your source folders follow the Maven default directory structure. That is, your test packages should be contained in a source folder called 'src/test/java', and the main project packages should go in 'src/main/java'. Otherwise Maven will not know where to find your source code. It is possible to configure a POM to tell Maven to expect your source code to be in different source folders, but it is highly recommended that you follow the standard Maven directory structure.

Since you have child modules, my suggestion would be to simplify things by creating a new Maven project from scratch that you can have a play around with. Once you are comfortable with that then try getting m2e to work for your multi-module project.

I remember your pain when first getting to grips with Maven, but it's great once you understand what it's doing and everything is working. I highly recommend reading through the free online book [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/) - it helped me out a lot when I was getting started with Maven.

Comment: So I need to try again with a new project, and then simply copy in all my classes from my current stuff. I'll check this out when I get a chance, and I'll set it up as a single project with a proper 'child' tree structure (rather than a flat one), as Eclipse seems to prefere this. Once I've tested it (and it works I'll mark your response as the solution... give the thread a bump in case I forget. For now though I'm back to ANT (maybe I'll try ivy with it?) David

Comment: Did you have any luck with Maven in the end?

Comment: I've kind of given maven the elbow. I've tried downloading the source of a few projects, and installing with maven even fails with them (which seems strange). I haven't really had time to fully investigate. However I have made a point of using a maven file/folder structure, so when I am ready I should be able to copy over the files to a full on test project. Fo now though I will stick with ANT (which does result in rather a long list of jar s in my manifest classpath as I get the list dynamically, and use the same code for all my projects, dirty but quicker that way). I thinking of trying Ivy?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same messages and have found a working solution, thanks to one of my organization's Maven experts.

Here was my pom.xml that **reproduces your error:**

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit4</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.junit4</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

With it, I would get `package org.junit does not exist` messages and `NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assert`. Similar to your experience, it worked great from Eclipse, green bars and all.

Here is the pom.xml **that works:**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I copied this from the example at the top of this Using [JUnit page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html).